# Numpy.array indexing question

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a 'mask' of a numpy.array by specifying certain criteria. Python even has nice syntax for something like this:

```
>> A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>> A > 3
array([False, False, False, True, True])
```

But if I have a list of criteria instead of a range:

```
>> A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>> crit = [1,3,5]
```

I can't do this:

```
>> A in crit
```

I have to do something based on list comprehensions, like this:

```
>> [a in crit for a in A]
array([True, False, True, False, True])
```

Which is correct.

Now, the problem is that I am working with large arrays and the above code is very slow. Is there a more natural way of doing this operation that might speed it up?

EDIT: I was able to get a small speedup by making crit into a set.

EDIT2: For those who are interested:

**Jouni's approach:**
1000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop

**numpy.in1d:**
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

EDIT3: Just tested again with B = randint(10,size=100)

**Jouni's approach:**
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop

**numpy.in1d:**
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop

**Conclusion**: Use numpy.in1d() unless B is very small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the numpy function `in1d` is what you are looking for:

```
>>> A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> B = [1,3,5]
>>> numpy.in1d(A,crit)
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

as stated in its docstring, "`in1d(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`"

Admittedly, I haven't done any speed tests, but it sounds like what you are looking for.

**Another faster way**

Here's another way to do it which is faster. Sort the B array first(containing the elements you are looking to find in A), turn it into a numpy array, and then do:

```
B[B.searchsorted(A)] == A
```

though if you have elements in A that are larger than the largest in B, you will need to do:

```
inds = B.searchsorted(A)
inds[inds == len(B)] = 0
mask = B[inds] == A
```

It may not be faster for small arrays (especially for B being small), but before long it will definitely be faster. Why? Because this is a O(N log M) algorithm, where N is the number of elements in A and M is the number of elements in M,  putting together a bunch of individual masks is O(N * M). I tested it with N = 10000 and M = 14 and it was already faster. Anyway, just thought that you might like to know, especially if you are truly planning on using this on very large arrays.

Comment: looks like a recent addition to numpy (wasn't in version 1.3)

Comment: You are right. I only tested on B having a length of 3. If B is also large, numpy.in1d() definitely scales a lot better.

Comment: @aduric and my second method is even faster than in1d.

Answer (score 3):

Combine several comparisons with "or":

```
A = randint(10,size=10000)
mask = (A == 1) | (A == 3) | (A == 5)
```

Or if you have a list B and want to create the mask dynamically:

```
B = [1, 3, 5]
mask = zeros((10000,),dtype=bool)
for t in B: mask = mask | (A == t)
```

Comment: just wondering why or how to anticipate when `numpy` will naturally do this `ufunc` enabled element-wise logical operation?  When doing logical operations `numpy` sometimes throws back an exception: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: this is certainly the fastest approach, albeit, not the cleanest one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask and use the compress function of the numpy array.  It should be much faster.
If you have a complex criteria, remember to construct it based on math of the arrays.

```
a = numpy.array([3,1,2,4,5])
mask = a > 3
b = a.compress(mask)
```

or

```
a = numpy.random.random_integers(1,5,100000)
c=a.compress((a<=4)*(a>=2)) ## numbers between n<=4 and n>=2
d=a.compress(~((a<=4)*(a>=2))) ## numbers either n>4 or n<2
```

Ok, if you want a mask that has all a in [1,3,5] you can do something like

```
a = numpy.random.random_integers(1,5,100000)
mask=(a==1)+(a==3)+(a==5)
```

or

```
a = numpy.random.random_integers(1,5,100000)
mask = numpy.zeros(len(a), dtype=bool)
for num in [1,3,5]:
    mask += (a==num)
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what I'm looking for. I don't want to get the actual contents of the array back, I just want to get a boolean mask that has the same length as the original array.

Comment: Ok, edited it now that I know what you want.  I guess Jouni's solution that he came up with while I was editing mine was equivalent, as True= True + True, True = True + False, False = False + False, exactly the same as or using |.